# How to correlate reps into training program when doing isometric exercises?

Tags: strength-training, reps, rock-climbing

I'm doing max weighted dead hangs. To improve grip/finger strength for climbing. I'm doing a lot of research on how to create training programs to increase max strength but everything I've seen so far is related to movements where reps are a range of motion. With this particular exercise, it's not as obvious (or is it?). How can I relate reps into my training program?

Note: I don't feel that hanging for 10s jumping off and jumping right back on and doing another 10s would be analogous to doing reps.

I'm also trying to build max strength so I want to keep my reps low and intensity high and I'm just confused as to how I can relate typical ROM exercises to isometrics.

Any ideas are welcomed. Any resources/studies are appreciated!

Comment: Just to clear something up: Why do you feel the need to measure "reps" at all? Isn't time a better counter for isometric exercises?

Comment: @Alec I'm using time and maybe that's my rep equivalent. But looking at training programs and more specifically Prilepin's chart. How do I get equate 18 total reps into a workout? Am I going to do 18 sets of one 10-second hang? That doesn't seem to make sense so perhaps fewer sets with a longer hang time of 45 seconds but then I'm no longer training max strength.

Answer (score 4):

**The fallacy of "counting repetitions" in isometrics**

I would caution against using [Prilepin's chart](https://www.google.com/search?q=Prilepin%27s%20chart) when it comes to measuring isometrics. The reason for this is something you already put very nicely. A "repetition" implies range of motion, and an isometric exercise has no range of motion. In fact, it has no motion at all.

**Another approach**

I would instead suggest that you simply figure out what weight you can hold for X seconds, and try to improve on them all.

For instance, let's say you can deadhang with

- 10kg for 70 seconds
- 20kg for 55 seconds
- 30kg for 30 seconds
- 40kg for 15 seconds
- 50kg for 5 seconds

Then on any given day you wish to measure progress, pick one, and note down positive change, if any.

On days you are not aiming to set a PB, train as usual. Of course, grip training should include more than just dead hangs, but that's a story for another question (which I encourage you to ask if you're into it, but be sure to search similar questions on the site first).

**Bottom line**

Prilepin's chart is a tool. [It has its uses, but](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument) counting isometric "repetitions" isn't one of them. Find a different tool. You can use the one I suggested, or find another one somewhere. I'm sure there are wiser people than me that have thought about this already.